# sql query join for more than 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have 4 tables:

```
 #table 1 columns - areacode,section_number,maint_charge
 #table 2 columns - section_number,discount,fee,total_Maint_charge
 #table 3 columns - areacode, statename
 #table 4 columns - section_number , customer
```

mapping goes like:

```
 #table1.areacode = #table3.areacode
 #table1.section_number = #table2.section_number
```

I want to get something like this:

```
 state,section_number,maint_charge,maint_charge/total_maint_charge,
 fee*(maint_charge/total_maint_charge)
```

Thanks

Comment: 3 table joins work just like 2 table joins. You just add another `join` clause.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT state,
    table1.section_number,
    maint_charge,
    (maint_charge / total_maint_charge),
    (fee * (maint_charge / total_maint_charge))
FROM table1
    JOIN table3 ON table1.areacode=table3.areacode
    JOIN table2 on table1.section_number=table2.section_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      t3.statename
    , t1.section_number
    , t1.maint_charge
    , t1.maint_charge / t2.total_maint_charge
    , t2.fee * (t1.maint_charge / t2.total_maint_charge)
FROM #table1 t1
JOIN #table2 t2 ON t1.section_number = t2.section_number
JOIN #table3 t3 ON t1.areacode = t3.areacode
```